# How can I declare an array in one function, pass its address and dynamically allocate it in another function (in C)?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm wondering how I can dynamically allocate and populate an array, and have the values available in another function. I wish to do this without any return values, and I therefore want to pass an address from function1 to function2, where function2 allocates memory pointed to by the address from function1. Here is a short example of pseudocode:

```
void func2(int **array)
{   
    // Read array length from a data file.

    *array = malloc(array_length*sizeof(int));

    // Set array values from a datafile.
}

void func1()
{       
    int *array;

    func2(&array);

    // Use array values
}
```

How can I do this? I have tried many times, but ultimately end up with either a 'Misaligned address error' or 'Address boundary error'. I ultimately wish to do this with a custom struct, but I believe the process is similar for a dynamically allocated array. Thanks a ton for any help!

Comment: what you have there pretty much does exactly what your title describes (save for vernacular; you're passing the address of a *pointer*, not an array). I suspect your issue is coming from the inconveniently omitted `// Set array values from a datafile.` and to that, I further suspect an operator precedence misunderstanding. Of course, without the actual code, nor a detail debug of where this goes off the rails, that's pure guesswork, which makes for lousy answers.

Comment: If you are still having trouble, please edit the question to include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: One issue you'll need to consider is how the calling function knows how big the array is — at the moment, `func2()` doesn't appear to have a way to communicate that (unless you've got `array_length` as a global variable, or file scope variable, but that would be nasty, especially as the array is not a global variable).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way:

```
void func2(int **array)
{
    // Read array length from a data file.

    *array = (int *)malloc(array_length*sizeof(int));

    // Set array values from a datafile.
    (*array)[0] = 2;
    (*array)[1] = 7;
}

void func1()
{
    int *array = NULL;

    func2(&array);

    // Use array values
    printf("\n%d", array[0]);
    printf("\n%d", array[1]);
}
```

Comment: This is a  C question